# Convert PIL image to OpenCV2 image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm using `entireScreen=ImageGrab.grab()` to create a screengrab and then conduct some analyses with openCV2 to test whether the screen contains certain template images. Those templates are loaded with `template = cv2.imread(name,0)`.

I have now the following problem: when comparing my screenshot with the templates I always need to first save my screenshot with this :

`entireScreen.save('pics/screenshot.png', format='png')`

And then reload it with :

`cv2.imread('screenshot.png',0)`

Otherwise the following will not work:

`res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,method)`

I would get an error message like this one:

`TypeError: image is not a numpy array, neither a scalar`

My question: how can I convert the screenshot from `entireScreen=ImageGrab.grab()` into a format that is compatible with opencv2, without having to save and then reload it with cv2.imread.

Comment: I don't have a Windows system set up at the moment, and attempting to import  `ImageGrab` tells me it is Windows-only, so this is only a guess:  pass `entireScreen` through `np.array()` to convert it to a numpy array before passing it to `cv2.matchTemple()`. I.e. `res = cv2.matchTemplate(np.array(entireScreen), template, method)`

Comment: Pretty useful tool by the way, this screengrab. Thanks for bringing up this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux systems, one can use [`pyscreenshot`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot) which as its `docs` state, is a replacement for the ImageGrab Module, which works on Windows only.

So, on my linux system I did something like this -

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
```

Then, you can grab the screenshot and have access to it directly in memory space as a numpy array without having to actually save onto disk and read with `imread`, like so -

```
img = np.array(ImageGrab.grab().convert('RGB'))
```

This `img` could then by used with `cv2.matchTemplate` as it is.

---

A step-by-step sample run and verification of output -

```
In [32]: import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

In [33]: img = np.array(ImageGrab.grab().convert('RGB'))

In [34]: img.shape
Out[34]: (768, 1366, 3)

In [35]: img.dtype
Out[35]: dtype('uint8')
```

Here's a sample run showing how `cv2.matchTemplate` could then be used with `img` -

```
In [41]: res = cv2.matchTemplate(img[:,:,0],img[10:40,50:80,0],cv2.TM_SQDIFF)

In [42]: np.where(res<10) # 10 is threshold for matching
Out[42]: (array([10]), array([50]))
```

Comment: That seems to work. Important to note that there aret two steps. First convert img to RGB and then img[:,:,0]

Comment: @Nicolas That was just an example run using the blue channel `[:,:,0]`. You might be using some other version of the input array, maybe it is the grayscale, maybe red channel or green channel or  some other modified version of the 3D RGB input array.

Comment: if I don't do [:,:,0] then I get an error saying: cv2.error: ..\..\..\opencv-3.0.0\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:910: error: (-215) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function cv::matchTemplate

Comment: @Nicolas I think template matching expects a 2D array. I have no idea how do you intend to use the template matching for your case. What I have shown as the sample run uses the blue channel, which is `img[;,:,0]`. How do you plan to use this template matching for your case?

Comment: template = cv2.imread('template.png',0);
        method = eval('cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED');
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,method); #the error occus in matchTemplate

Comment: @Nicolas In that case, you can directly do `img = np.array(ImageGrab.grab().convert('L'))` , giving us a 2D grayscale image, which could be used as it is with template matching function.